# How to get the text in the custom dialog to be centered vertically

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

How would I go about amending the HTML or CSS markup below to have the text that is in my custom dialog box, to be vertically centered in the white space. Here is a snapshot of the problem:
[image]

and the expected result:
[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

#container {
    background: #FFF;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(100,139,170);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.topbar {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(100,139,170);
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#Text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="container">

        <div style="float:left;" class="topbar">Custom Dialog Box</div><div class="topbar" style="text-align: right;">Close</div>

        <div id="Text">This is some sample text that will appear here</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Fiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/vc5xL1vy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to set the container to `display: table;` and set all its children to `display: table-cell` but the table header to `display: table-caption`. I have made a few other modification to your header to a single div wrapper. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1s45cdvs/1/

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

#container {
    background: #FFF;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(100,139,170);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display:table;
}
.topbar {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(100,139,170);
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-caption;
}

#Text {
  text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="container">

        <div class="topbar">
            <div style="float:left;" >Custom Dialog Box</div><div style="text-align: right;">Close</div>
        </div>

        <div id="Text">This is some sample text that will appear here</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways to do this but they all require you to set a pixel value for something. Padding, line-height, etc...
You can set the container display as table-cell to act like a table element would, then set width and height of the text container so that the element knows where the middle is. Using % never works for vertical aligning. Pain in the CSS.

```
#Text {
  width: 500px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bgbfpbta/